# Как ограничить возможность записи данных в админке Django при выполнении условия

Tags: django-admin, django-model

Всем салют. Есть модель с данными на сотрудников. Как описать условие так, чтоб при вводе в поле "Что должность вакантна" остальные поля стали недоступны. Вся работа происходит только в админке Django. Т.е. если я установил дату (DateField) что должность вакантна, остальные все записи для меня становятся недоступными для ввода данных

Comment: Не надо писать приветствие в заголовке вопроса. Если хочешь кого-то приветствовать - напиши в самом __тексте вопроса__.

Comment: Буду иметь в виду. Спасибо